# configuration failed for xml2 while installing tidyverse in r studio

Tags: r, tidyverse

system: ubuntu 18.04
Rstudio version 3.4.4

Whenever i try to install tidyverse this error comes up, how do i add the directory containing the lib-curl to the package configuration search path?

```
 installing source package ‘curl’ ...
 package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
.
.
.
.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’

removing ‘/home/javed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2’

Warning in install.packages :

  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status


ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/javed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/httr’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/javed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rvest’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’

* removing ‘/home/javed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyverse’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 9):

Install these missing dependencies before installing R packages:

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

Source: https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-01-29/installing-r-r-packages-e-g-tidyverse-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

1. **Quit R and open up a command window and confirm that libcurl is indeed not installed on Ubuntu**

`apt list --installed | grep libcurl`

You should see no results.

2. **Install the package**

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

3. **Open up R and reinstall tidyverse.**

If you still get error messages in R, you might have to install additional missing Linux packages by repeating similar steps.

Comment: It is not really necessary to quit RStudio in order to install anything with `apt`.